# Apache rewritemod redirecting to realpath

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a streaming app and I want my links to be as easylooking as possible. I choosed to use the rewritemod using the format **/streaming/stream_type/stream_name/season/episode/version**, exemple */streaming/ser/stargate_atlantis/2/13/vf*.
So I created a .htaccess into the streaming directory with the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(ser|mov)/(?:(\w[\w_]*\w)/(?:(\d+)/(?:(\d+)/(\w{0,10})?)?)?)?$ _dispatch.php?type=$1&sn=$2&s=$3&ep=$4&ver=$5 [L]
```

It works perfectly, but now I want the users that calls **/streaming/stream_type** to be redirected to **/streaming/stream_type/** adding the slash for him, and the same for the series name, the season, etc. I looked on the web and saw you can add `[R=301]` so the browser redirects to the replaced uri and not only apache

I tried to add the following rule for try if it really works:

```
RewriteRule ^ser$ ser/ [L,R=301]
```

But I get a redirection to the realpath of the file like this: http://wawolf/streaming/ser => http://wawolf/C:/wamp/www/wawolf%202.1/streaming/ser/

What's happening? It's a simple replace, but apache redirects it to http://server/absolute_path/, not even http://server/streaming/absolute_path while .htaccess which contains the rule is inside the streaming directory.

Worst, I removed the directive, restarted apache, my computer,  **and it's still doing the same thing**!

Thank you in advance, Pierre, that needs a Xtra large buoy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to absence of `RewriteBase`.

Or just have full path in target:

```
RewriteRule ^ser$ /ser/ [L,R=301]
```